# simple Delete() command on sqlite takes nearly a second?

Tags: android, sqlite

A call to the delete() command  in a database helper class is causing a lag in the UI of my android application. I did a timer test on it and the simple command   this.db.delete("tonightSets", "id = "+item_id, null); takes ages to return.
Here are the speeds I got for executing the same query repeatedly (in milliseconds)
1229ms
287ms
779ms
2604ms  !
817ms
Why is this so slow? The table only has 30 records in it and each row has about ten columns. I'm doing far more complicated multiple select and count functions on the same table that return in less than 9ms
How can I fix this? is there a way to do it asynchronously so it doesn't create a lag in the UI?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this so slow?

If you are running this on a device, welcome to flash I/O. Flash I/O can be very slow, depending on what else is all going on with the device. Most Android devices use the YAFFS2 filesystem, which uses a global partition lock to single-thread access to the filesystem. And flash writes are slower yet, due to wear-level balancing and whatnot.

You should watch Brad Fitzpatrick's "Writing Zippy Android Apps" presentation from the 2010 Google I|O conference. In there, he indicates that writing a single byte to flash -- while normally very speedy -- can sometimes take 200ms.

Hence, the general recommendation is to not do flash I/O on the main application thread.

> is there a way to do it asynchronously so it doesn't create a lag in the UI?

Use an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into the AsyncTask, out of interest though is there any reason why the delete was consistently between 20 and 200 times slower than actually accessing the database and pulling out a multidimensional array?

Comment: just a note to rookies such as myself! I had a major aha moment when after over a year of putting up with slow inserts into sqlite I realised I'd been overlooking the `beginTransaction()` etc. commands for multiple inserts. It has given me a 500% increase in speed on writing to database!